# set the bits of a variable according to the low-order n bits of another variable

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, bitmask

I have two `uint64` variables `var_1` and `var_2` and I want to set the bits of `var_1` according to the low-order `6` bits of `var_2`. How can I do this in C language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so:

```
uint64_t mask = 0x3F;
var_1 &= (~mask);
var_1 |= (var_2 & mask);
```

Comment: thx a lot! but shouldn't be var_1 exchanged with var_2 and var_2 with var_1 in your example?

Comment: @hawidere I read your question wrong, you're correct. I'll edit my answer